# linq query for set attribute

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have 2 class lists,

```
List<CommunityGroups> List1=new List<CommunityGroups>();
List<CommunityGroups> List1=new List<CommunityGroups>();

public class CommunityGroups
{
    public long CommunityID { get; set; }
    public string CommunityName { get; set; }
}
```

In these lists, List1 10 CommunityGroups which has both CommunityID and CommunityName.
List2 contais 5 CommunityGroups which has CommunityID and blank CommunityNames. I need to populate the CommunityNames in List2 with respect to List1.
Now I am using the code,

```
for (int i = 0; i < List2.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < List1.Length; j++)
        {
            if (List2[i].GroupId == List1[j].Id)
            {
                List2[i].GroupName = List1[j].Name;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I need to use linq query for this purpose. How can I replace these code with linq. Please someone help me.

Thanks

Comment: Where are the `GroupId`, `GroupName`, `Name` and `Id` defined in `CommunityGroups`?

Comment: Why do you have to use Linq? Linq is for *querying*, not for setting properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translation (changed names so they match class definition) with maximized linq:

```
foreach (CommunityGroups t in List2)
{
    foreach (CommunityGroups t1 in List1.Where(t1 => t.GroupId == t1.GroupId))
    {
        t.GroupName = t1.GroupName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could query the two lists with a `join`, and then run through the enumerated pairs making the assignment:

```
var combineditems = from item1 in List1
                    join item2 in List2
                    on item1.Id equals item2.GroupId
                    select new { item1 , item2  };

foreach(var items in combineditems)
    items.item2.GroupName  = items.item2.Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just filter the rows from first list as it contains both Id and Name where id is in second list and create a new list or assign it to List2.

```
List2 = List1.Where( x => List2.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
```

You can also do a join  from list1 and list2 and then select name and description. Compare in terms of performance and choose any method that you like.

Answer (score 2):

```
var newList = List2.Foreach( x => x.Name = List1.First(m => m.Id == x.Id).Name);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 foreach (CommunityGroups t1 in List2)
        {
            foreach (var t in List1.Where(t => t1.GroupId == t.Id))
            {
                t1.GroupName = t.Name;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query =
     from l1 in List1
     join l2 in List2
          on l1.CommunityID equals l2.CommunityID
     select l2;
```

Comment: This is a only query definition, which will not be executed. Also this query, even if you will execute it, do not update list2 items.

Answer (score 1):

In general LINQ statements do not contain side effects.

However, it is possible to write a statement such as:

```
list2.Join(list1,
           l2 => l2.CommunityID,
           l1 => l1.CommunityID,
           (item2, item1) =>
               {
                   item2.CommunityName = item1.CommunityName;
                   return item2;
               }
           ).ToList();
```

I would recommend the `foreach` approach since it conveys the correct meaning of mutability.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert first list to dictionary with id as key and name as value:

```
var names = List1.ToDictionary(l1 => l1.CommunityID, l1 => l1.CommunityName);
foreach (var l2 in List2)
    if (names.ContainsKey(l2.CommunityID))
        l2.CommunityName = names[l2.CommunityID];
```